# When reading input from a File, not all my the lines in the file are read in Java?

Tags: java, file-io

So for an assignment i had to read input from a file and then output it.
The information in the file was in the following format: 1 line with a stock symbol and the next line with the quantity bought.
eg of a file that we'd use:

```
.ab
15
mox
16
.fy
8
mixe
34
```

And then i have to output the count and total price of each symbol.
But somehow when i run it, it only reads the first 3 sets of data - there are only 3 lines of data instead of 4 for this example.
eg. output would be:

```
Enter filename ... lab5data.txt
00000 54.05
00002 Symbol mox does not exist
00003 10.70
00004 Symbol mixe does not exist
```

**And my code would not output the last line "00004 Symbol mixe does not exist"**

This is my code:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.io.PrintStream;
import type.lib.Stock;
import java.io.File;
import java.text.DecimalFormat;
public class Check05B
{
    public static void main(String[] args) throws java.io.IOException
    {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        PrintStream output = new PrintStream(System.out);
        output.print("Enter filename ... ");
        String fileName = input.nextLine();
        Scanner fileInput = new Scanner(new File(fileName));
        double totalValue = 0;
        int count = 00000;
        String symbol = fileInput.next();
        int quantity = fileInput.nextInt();
        while (fileInput.hasNext())
        {
            Stock myStock = new Stock(symbol);
            double total = myStock.getPrice() * quantity;
            String aFormatCounter = new DecimalFormat("00000").format(count);
            if (myStock.getName() == null)
            output.println(aFormatCounter + " Symbol " + symbol + " does not exist!");
            else
            output.printf("%s %.2f%n", aFormatCounter, myStock.getPrice());
            totalValue += total;
            symbol = fileInput.next();
            count++;
            quantity = fileInput.nextInt();
            count++;
        }
        output.printf("Total value = %.2f%n", totalValue);
        fileInput.close();
    }
}
```

Could anybody please help? How can i make it read all the lines? Thanks!!

Comment: You'll need to include the code for the `Stock` class in your question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to have the reading of `symbol` and `quantity` at the top of you loop.

Consider

```
    while (fileInput.hasNext())
    {
        String symbol = fileInput.next();
        if (fileInput.hasNextInt () == false) {
            System.err.println ("File Format Error - expecting an int");
            break;
        }    
        int quantity = fileInput.nextInt();
        Stock myStock = new Stock(symbol);
        double total = myStock.getPrice() * quantity;
        String aFormatCounter = new DecimalFormat("00000").format(count);
        if (myStock.getName() == null) {
            output.println(aFormatCounter + " Symbol " + symbol + " does not exist!");
        }
        else {
            output.printf("%s %.2f%n", aFormatCounter, myStock.getPrice());
        }
        totalValue += total;
        count = count + 2;
    }
```

Comment: Yes that solved it!! Thank You so much!! :)
I would have "thumbed up" your post but i dont have enough reputation points yet! Thanks again!!

Comment: Would you consider a double check, something like `while(hasNext) { if (hasNextInt) { ...` or is that just been massively nit picky and beyond the scope of the question ;)

Comment: @MadProgrammer How about `not nit picky but beyond the scope of the question`.  But seriously I will add it.

Comment: @ScaryWombat It was only a passing idea +1 though ;)